# iOS 8 causing trouble with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlsession

I have a fairly complex iPad app that has been live in the app store for months that makes extensive use of `NSURLSession` to interact with *.php* files on a web server to read and write files to the web server.  The networking portion of the app now either works intermittently (or not at all) on devices that are running *iOS 8*.  Has anyone seen anything similar occur with their app?

I will start the painstaking forensics this weekend, but just thought I would ask here first to see if anyone else had run into this.

I haven't yet found any known issues in the Apple Docs concerning NSURLSession and iOS 8.  I have recompiled the app with *XCode 6.0.1* and run it on a test device and it still exhibits the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this, but can't explain why it is a solution.  This is the code I use to set up the NSURLSession:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30;
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60;
sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
sessionConfig.URLCache = NULL;

//Create the session with the newly created sessionConfig.
session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

This line of code was the culprit

```
sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
```

I simply increased 1 to 10 and viola, it works correctly on iOS 8 as well now.  I have no idea why this runs perfectly on iOS 7 with the value set to 1, but not on iOS 8.  The only thing that I can think of is that maybe Apple changed the internal workings of NSURLSession.

Comment: I had the same problem. I used NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount to let iOS decide the amount of connections per host but seems to fail since iOS 8.